# where_am_i debugger / breakpoint helper -- codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I was working on last few days with codeigniter framework, what i found is debugging is not as simple as i thought when lines of code increases.

i am basically looking for something intrinsic to identify all variable values and the path program took to reach a specific point.

> e.g User/login>>User_model>> user_login_view.php>>User/login>>Post/Article>>Post_model>>Error!

one way to achieve this is 
add $navigatedpath=array(); in session
add below line in every method to catch the navigated path.

```
array_push($navigatedpath,$this->router->fetch_class()."/".$this->router->fetch_method());
```

i also used profiler with all options set TRUE, but it wont catch variables.. want to ask Aces here, whats the best way for debugging when we are dealing with 30+ controllers application and respective models views assets.... is there some better practice than run code,see error,debug >> fix and run it again everytime ?

```
  $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
        $sections = array(
          'benchmarks' => TRUE,
          'get' => TRUE,
          'memory_usage' => TRUE,
          'post' => TRUE,
          'uri_string' => TRUE,
          'controller_info' => TRUE,
          'queries' => TRUE,
          'http_headers' => TRUE,
          'session_data' => TRUE,
          'config' => TRUE    );
          $this->output->set_profiler_sections($sections);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [xdebug](https://xdebug.org) for debugging PHP on the localhost;

together with any IDE, which supports it; eg. [NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org), [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download), etc.

this gives you break-points & watches.

Comment: I prefer VS Code. It supports XDebug and is much friendlier than Eclipse.

Comment: @MartinZeitler i am using Atom IDE, is integration possible? if yes, how was your experience of using Xdebug with Atom? Thanks.

Comment: @Niru there also is an extension for it (which most likely requires separate install of `xdebug` itself): https://atom.io/packages/php-debug

Answer (score 0):

[PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/) is a very widely used PHP testing tool. However, due to the way CodeIgniter (CI) is structured it can be hard (or impossible) to use PHPUnit with CI. To overcome those problems the third-party tool [ci-phpunit-test](http://kenjis.github.io/ci-phpunit-test/) was developed provide a way to use PHPUnit with CodeIgniter 3.x.

PHPUnit is NOT a debugging tool. It is a unit testing framework that uses assertions to verify that the behavior of the specific component ("unit") being tested behaves as expected.